# Iterate through class objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have defined class this way:

```
class Vehicules(object):
    class Car(object):
        INSTANCES = 5
        WIDTH = 5
        HEIGHT = 4

    class Bike(object):
        INSTANCES = 3
        WIDTH = 3
        HEIGHT = 4

    class Pedestrian(object):
        INSTANCES = 2
        WIDTH = 2
        HEIGHT = 4
```

I'm looking for a way to execute a script that goes along these lines:

```
for obj in Vehicules:
     print(obj.INSTANCES)
```

Any idea how to achieve that please?

Comment: To be able iterate through a class object, you have to implement the metaclass's `__iter__`.

Comment: But why are you using classes like this?

Comment: Alternatively, you can iterate through the namespace of the class, e.g. `for name, attribute in Vehicules.__dict__.items()` or equivalently `for name, attribute in vars(Vehicules).items():`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Vehicules(object):
    class Car(object):
        INSTANCES = 5
        WIDTH = 5
        HEIGHT = 4

    class Bike(object):
        INSTANCES = 3
        WIDTH = 3
        HEIGHT = 4

    class Pedestrian(object):
        INSTANCES = 2
        WIDTH = 2
        HEIGHT = 4
all_vehicle_classes = [c for c in vars(Vehicules).values() if isinstance(c, type(Vehicules))]
for inner_class in all_vehicle_classes:
    print(inner_class.INSTANCES)
```

F.Y.I: Inner classes are generally avoided.

Comment: `isinstance(c, type(Vehicules))` is confusing. Why not just `isinstance(c, type)`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I did not know that it works that way too :) Thanks